# sql select from multiple tables join not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query selecting from 2 subqueries and a left join. problem is the left join is not recognising the subqueries correctly and i am not sure why. it is not recognising `dt.timestamp`

```
SELECT dt.TIMESTAMP
    ,count(*)
    ,tc.total_cells - count(*)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT TIMESTAMP
    FROM (
        SELECT to_char(trunc(TIMESTAMP, 'hh24'), 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') TIMESTAMP
        FROM t_date_time
        WHERE trunc(TIMESTAMP, 'dd') = to_date('16-mar-17', 'dd-mon-yy')
        ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
        )
    ORDER BY to_date(TIMESTAMP, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')
    ) dt,
  (
        SELECT count(DISTINCT cell) total_cells
        FROM t_ca_processed
        WHERE trunc(TIMESTAMP, 'dd') = trunc(to_date('16-mar-17', 'dd-mon-yy'), 'dd')
        ) tc
LEFT JOIN t_ca_processed p ON dt.timestamp = to_char(p.TIMESTAMP, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')
GROUP BY dt.TIMESTAMP
ORDER BY to_date(dt.TIMESTAMP, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')
```

Comment: which db are you using?

Comment: Where is the join between dt and tc?

Comment: it doesnt need one, ORACLE. I need `tc` to display on all rows for my calculation

Comment: If you dont need a `JOIN` use `CROSS JOIN` is more clear than a single comma `,`

Comment: what you mean `problem is the left join is not recognising the subqueries correctly` ?? Show us sample data and expected output.

Comment: I am not sure how to do this here

Comment: check this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42817997/mysql-how-to-get-a-sum-of-start-end-dates-with-possible-overlapping-dates/42819310#42819310

Comment: it will be hard to show data but on the left join in SQL Dev when i type `dt.` it shows `total_cells` and not `timestamp`.

Comment: if i change to cross join it says not valid `group by exp`

Answer (score 0):

**

```
SELECT dt.TIMESTAMP
    ,count(*)
    ,tc.total_cells - count(*)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT TIMESTAMP
    FROM (
        SELECT to_char(trunc(TIMESTAMP, 'hh24'), 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') TIMESTAMP
        FROM t_date_time
        WHERE trunc(TIMESTAMP, 'dd') = to_date('16-mar-17', 'dd-mon-yy')
        ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
        )
    ORDER BY to_date(TIMESTAMP, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')
    ) dt
    left join 
  (
        SELECT count(DISTINCT cell) total_cells
        FROM t_ca_processed
        WHERE trunc(TIMESTAMP, 'dd') = trunc(to_date('16-mar-17', 'dd-mon-yy'), 'dd')
        ) tc
ON dt.timestamp = --(tc.something)--to_char(p.TIMESTAMP, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')
GROUP BY dt.TIMESTAMP
ORDER BY to_date(dt.TIMESTAMP, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')
```

**

> and you need to add TIMESTAMP column in TC query also then only we can match DT and TC

Answer (score 0):

Compiler doesn't like mixed join notation (, vs left join)

One approach would be to use a Common table Expression (CTE) to materialize the cross join data then use it in your left join.

```
WITH TC AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT TIMESTAMP
    FROM (
        SELECT to_char(trunc(TIMESTAMP, 'hh24'), 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') TIMESTAMP
        FROM t_date_time
        WHERE trunc(TIMESTAMP, 'dd') = to_date('16-mar-17', 'dd-mon-yy')
        ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
        )
    ORDER BY to_date(TIMESTAMP, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')
    ) dt,
  (
        SELECT count(DISTINCT cell) total_cells
        FROM t_ca_processed
        WHERE trunc(TIMESTAMP, 'dd') = trunc(to_date('16-mar-17', 'dd-mon-yy'), 'dd')
        )
SELECT dt.TIMESTAMP
    ,count(*)
    ,tc.total_cells - count(*)
FROM  tc
LEFT JOIN t_ca_processed p ON dt.timestamp = to_char(p.TIMESTAMP, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')
GROUP BY dt.TIMESTAMP
ORDER BY to_date(dt.TIMESTAMP, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')
```